# Result.java: variable shows null value?

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Here is my Result.java file from the model, made with the Google API and also the G0etter and Setter methods. But when I fetch the value from Result.java class, it shows null.

```
private String icon;
private String place_id;
private Reviews[] reviews;
private String scope;
private String rating;
private String phone;
private String website;
private String international_phone_number;
private String adr_address;
private String url;
private String reference;
private Geometry geometry;
private OpeningHours open_hours;
private String utc_offset;
private String id;
private Photo[] photo;
private String vicinity;
private Address_components[] address_components;
private String name;
private String formatted_address;
private String formatted_phone_number;
private String[] types;
```

Comment: what are you doing before fetch. Show you code if it is possible.

Comment: For example, I fetch the rating so I write the following code, It works but other remaining variables shows data to null. //Rating
        if (Common.currentResult.getRating() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(Common.currentResult.getRating())) {
            ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(Common.currentResult.getRating()));
        } else {
            ratingBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }